# Fillna in cycle with groupby

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, cycle, fillna

there is df like this one:

```
`import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'segment': ['flowers', 'toys', 'gifts', 'gifts', 'toys', 'toys', 'flowers',     'flowers'],
 'category': ['dandelion', 'car' , 'gift_1', 'gift_2', 'barby', 'gun', 'azalea','begonia'],
 'discount 15%': [11, 8, 'NaN', 6, 6, 5, 9, 12],
 'discount 20%': [15,'NaN', 15, 7, 9, 8, 'NaN', 14],
 'discount 30%': [25, 10, 25, 9, 'NaN', 9, 13, 16],
 'discount 40%': [35, 13, 'NaN', 15, 25, 11, 'NaN', 21]})`
```

The problem is to fill NaN values with median grouped by category, if there is no value to measure then median grouped by segment in 1 cycle. Nan values are only in the columns from 'discount 15%' till 'discount 40%'.

I've tried many variants like this but nothing works :C

```
`for col in df:
   for i in col:
      if i == 'Nan':
          df[col] = df[col].fillna(df.groupby(['category'])[col].transform('median'))

for col in df:
   for i in col:
      if i == 'Nan':
          df[col] = df[col].fillna(df.groupby(['segment'])[col].transform('median'))`
```

Thank you in advance for your time spent on the answer!

Comment: what you want to do is unclear, please provide the expected output and break down the calculation for a few of the filled values

Comment: Hello Mozway. I would like to fill all NaN values with median groud by category or segment. df['discount 15%'] = df['discount 15%'].fillna(df.groupby(['category'])['discount 15%'].transform('median'))
df['discount 15%'] = df['discount 15%'].fillna(df.groupby(['segment'])['discount 15%'].transform('median')) and the same logic for other columns. Am i more clear enough ?:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use:

```
import numpy as np

df = df.replace('NaN', np.nan)
cat = df.groupby('category').transform('median', numeric_only=True)
seg = df.groupby('segment').transform('median', numeric_only=True)

df = df.fillna(cat).fillna(seg)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   segment   category  discount 15%  discount 20%  discount 30%  discount 40%
0  flowers  dandelion          11.0          15.0          25.0          35.0
1     toys        car           8.0           8.5          10.0          13.0
2    gifts     gift_1           6.0          15.0          25.0          15.0
3    gifts     gift_2           6.0           7.0           9.0          15.0
4     toys      barby           6.0           9.0           9.5          25.0
5     toys        gun           5.0           8.0           9.0          11.0
6  flowers     azalea           9.0          14.5          13.0          28.0
7  flowers    begonia          12.0          14.0          16.0          21.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another coding style (even if the idea of using `transform` is very good):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'segment': ['flowers', 'toys', 'gifts', 'gifts', 'toys', 'toys', 'flowers',     'flowers'],
 'category': ['dandelion', 'car' , 'gift_1', 'gift_2', 'barby', 'gun', 'azalea','begonia'],
 'discount 15%': [11, 8, 'NaN', 6, 6, 5, 9, 12],
 'discount 20%': [15,'NaN', 15, 7, 9, 8, 'NaN', 14],
 'discount 30%': [25, 10, 25, 9, 'NaN', 9, 13, 16],
 'discount 40%': [35, 13, 'NaN', 15, 25, 11, 'NaN', 21]})

filtr = lambda x: np.median([e for e in x if float(e)==float(e)])

r = (df.groupby(['segment', 'category'])
       .apply(lambda d: d.iloc[0, 2:].astype(float).fillna(filtr(d.iloc[0, 2:])))
       .reset_index()
       )

print(r)
```

```
   segment   category  discount 15%  discount 20%  discount 30%  discount 40%
0  flowers     azalea           9.0          11.0          13.0          11.0
1  flowers    begonia          12.0          14.0          16.0          21.0
2  flowers  dandelion          11.0          15.0          25.0          35.0
3    gifts     gift_1          20.0          15.0          25.0          20.0
4    gifts     gift_2           6.0           7.0           9.0          15.0
5     toys      barby           6.0           9.0           9.0          25.0
6     toys        car           8.0          10.0          10.0          13.0
7     toys        gun           5.0           8.0           9.0          11.0
```